# Difficulty returning the result of an inner function in Angular / Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, observable

I am really new to Angular and Typescript.

I have this function right now

```
createTranscriptionJob(fileToUpload: File, language: string): Observable<void> {

    this.getSasUrl(fileToUpload.name, language, ldapUserName)
        .subscribe(response => {
            const test = this.upload(response.sasUrl, fileToUpload);
            console.log(test);
        });

    return of();
}
```

First problem currently is that the `createTranscriptionJob` function is returning basically nothing.

Second problem is that the `createTranscriptionJob` function is returning *before* the completion of the inner `upload` function call.

### Question

I would need the `createTranscriptionJob` function to return the result of the `upload` function. How to achieve that?

Something like that, but it's complaining:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to chain your observables with an operator like `switchMap`.

Doing so, you will need the called to do the subscribe.

```
createTranscriptionJob(fileToUpload: File, language: string): Observable<void> {
    return this.getSasUrl(fileToUpload.name, language, ldapUserName)
       .pipe(
           switchMap(() =>  this.upload(response.sasUrl, fileToUpload)
        )
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use alse the async/await pattern:

```
async createTranscriptionJob(fileToUpload: File, language: string) {

    var response = await this.getSasUrl(fileToUpload.name, language, ldapUserName).toPromise();
    
    // this line depends on the reponse type of upload method (toPromise() must be added if is an observable)
    const test = await this.upload(response.sasUrl, fileToUpload);

    console.log(test);

    return test;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not test this yet, but it is so much more understandable to me with async/await lol, I will give it a try

Comment: @Bruno is the same for me, you are welcome ;)